# CodeAnalysisRuleSet not working with Directory.Build.props

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stylecop

When I am using `Directory.Build.props` file for defining [StyleCop](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop) analyzer and the custom global ruleset for it, those second one are not taken into account. I mean `stylecop.json` defined in `Directory.Build.props` works globally, but `loans.ruleset` does not work in general.

All this I tried regards this [repo](https://github.com/hubert-wojtowicz/LoansManagerRestApi).

When I install `StyleCop.Analyzers` package into single project and include `loans.ruleset` it works fine for WebAPI project (this can be precisely reflected by commits [cd1b1f2](https://github.com/hubert-wojtowicz/LoansManagerRestApi/commit/cd1b1f27842130e0d0b331985b04598082465b91) and [53b4a4c](https://github.com/hubert-wojtowicz/LoansManagerRestApi/commit/53b4a4cc23609100cb2a6bba6935465e2880b3e7)).
I tried then to move those to work global here [ff8b017](https://github.com/hubert-wojtowicz/LoansManagerRestApi/commit/ff8b0174a35333694d4a18f160482e68fd41178c). The result is StyleCop works, but ruleset for it not.

Below overview:

```
    Directory: C:\Repos\LoansManagerRestApi


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       03.06.2019     08:50                LoansManager
d-----       03.06.2019     08:48                LoansManager.DAL
d-----       03.06.2019     08:48                LoansManager.Domain
d-----       03.06.2019     08:48                LoansManager.E2ETest
d-----       03.06.2019     08:48                LoansManager.Services
d-----       03.06.2019     08:48                LoansManager.UnitTest
d-----       03.06.2019     08:48                LoansManager.Util
-a----       02.06.2019     21:07           5912 .gitignore
-a----       03.06.2019     08:49            271 .stylecop.json
-a----       03.06.2019     08:57            338 Directory.Build.props
-a----       03.06.2019     08:51            348 loans.ruleset
-a----       02.06.2019     21:40           4208 LoansManager.sln
-a----       02.06.2019     21:07           1360 README.md
```

Directory.Build.props:

```
<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)loans.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118" />

    <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory).stylecop.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

loans.ruleset:

```
<RuleSet Name="StyleCopRules" Description="These rules configure StyleCop." ToolsVersion="1.0">
  <Rules AnalyzerId="StyleCop.Analyzers" RuleNamespace="StyleCop.Analyzers">
    <Rule Id="SA1101" Action="None" />
    <Rule Id="SA1633" Action="None" />
    <Rule Id="SA1600" Action="None" />
    <Rule Id="SA1615" Action="None" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

To summarize I need help to have `stylecop.json` and `loans.ruleset` rules applied to solution globally with use `Directory.Build.props` file, to not configure it per each project separately.

Answer (score 2):

It can be marked as resolved.

The problem was each of `*.csproj` files in solution had autogenerated by VS lines of xml PropertyGroups:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet />
  </PropertyGroup>
```

whose overshadow `Directory.Build.props`.

Comment: How do you fix this?

Comment: @UltimaWeapon you just remove those msbuild attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Importing [package](https://github.com/hubert-wojtowicz/Experiments/tree/master/%5Bc%23-global%20solution%20package%5D/LoansAnalyzerSettings) containing StyleCop analyzer dependency and its settings (`stylecop.json` and `.ruleset` file) with use simple `Directory.Build.props` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="loans.stylecop" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

works as expected in this question even in VS EE 2019 v16.1.1, but it is not perfect workaround as every rule change require package project versioning, building and publishing so **it still does not satisfy my expectations**.

Comment: Hi Lissajous, I'm currently trying to get stylecop enabled in this way and can't seem to reference any Packages in the Directory.build.props. Therefore, the solution you added as the "correct answer" won't work for me. It also is preferable for me to have each project list it's own references so I actually prefer this method you're mentioning above. So I just wanted to share my own $0.02 - You can do what you're describing above, but set the version to: "[1.*,2)". The idea is, it will automatically take the latest of version 1, all the way up to Version 2. This idea will work perfectly for me!